# replacement functionality for imp.load_module() in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import

The imp module in Google App Engine is empty.
Therefore, is there another way to do what the `imp.load_module()` function does -- namely, to return a module object from a file object?

(or even more generally -- even a way to generate a module object from any random piece of code (sent to exec() or something)?)

Comment: Please select the best answer for each of your questions.

Comment: They are both good answers :).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try:

```
>>> import types
>>> foo = types.ModuleType('foo')
```

But it will obviously be empty, and you'll have to "fill" it some other way, including

```
>>> exec('bar=2', foo.__dict__)
>>> foo.bar
2
```

The big question is why you would want that. Executing a "random piece of code" is generally a very bad idea. :-) It's a security hole in any situation, and if you somehow allow editing of this TTW, you are just *asking* for someone to hack your site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at `__import__`? [See here...](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) It returns a module too. What were your reasons for using `imp` though?